# Como ler arquivos txt e colocar seus dados em um vetor

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou tentando fazer um codigo que leia latitudes e longitudes que estão em um arquivo txt. ou seja, colocar o que está no arquivo em um vetor e fazer um laço for para chamar todos dentro da polyline.

```
   try {

        File file = getFileStreamPath("circular_1.txt");//se eu puder usar uma variavel aki seria melhor pois o nome do arquivo vai ir sempre mudando
        int x = 0;
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("ufpa_circular_1.txt")));
        Double[] coord = new Double[192];
        String linha;
        while ((linha = leitor.readLine()) != null) {
            coord[x++] =Double.parseDouble(linha);
        }
        for (x = 0; x < 192; x = x + 2) {
            Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(coord[x], coord[x + 1]), new LatLng(coord[x + 2], coord[x + 3]))
                    .width(5)
                    .color(Color.BLUE));

        }
        leitor.close();
        reader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

o problema é que a polyline nunca aparece quando coloco esse codigo e nao estou encontrando o erro nele.
ja tentei colocar o arquivo no raw e usar R.raw e no assets e usar o getAssets(), nenhum dos dois abriu a polyline tambem
as linhas estao sem delimitaçoes, ou seja, so dei enter mesmo pra ir pra outra linha, mas antes tinha feito um texto delimitando com ; e usando stringtokenizer e tambem nao apareceu as polylines

Comment: Seu problema é ler o arquivo, tranformar em Polyline ou exibir os dados? Não enetendi qual é o problema. Os dados são carregados corretamente no Polyline?

Comment: Tem certeza que você está lendo do arquivo certo? O fato de usar dois arquivos (nas variáveis "reader" e "leitor"), mas só ler de um deles me parece muito suspeito.

Comment: O título da pergunta não bate com a descrição. O título diz que o problema está em carregar dados de um txt em um vetor. A descrição diz que você está tendo problema com as polylines. Você conseguiu ou não carregar os dados no vetor?